# How to get a Finepoint Digitizer Tablet to work under Fedora Core 16?

Tags: fedora, configuration, input, tablet

How to get a Finepoint Digitizer Tablet to work under Fedora Core 16?

The hardware in question is a Gateway m285-E. It uses an active pen (has a battery in the pen).

```
    cat /dev/ttyS0
```

returns input characters to the screen when the pen is close to the monitor. However, if I don't cat /dev/ttyS0 – say I'm just on the desktop, and press the pen to the screen, it crashes me back out to the Fedora login screen. How do I get this laptop to handle pen input properly?

Let me recap what we've tried so far:

Here's the modified contents of xorg.conf:

```
  Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Tablet"
  EndSection

  Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "Tablet"
    Driver "fpit"
    Option "Device" "/dev/ttyS0"
    Option "AlwaysCore" "on"
    Option "InvertY"
    Option "MaximumXPosition" "12550"
    Option "MaximumYPosition" "7650"
    Option "MinimumXPosition" "400"
    Option "MinimumYPosition" "400"
    Option "SendCoreEvents"
  EndSection
```

Here's the contents of her /home/[user]/.xinitrc:

```
    xsetpointer TOUCHSCREEN
    xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 3 2"
```

Here's the contents of /etc/serial.conf

```
    /dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A port 0x06a8 irq 4 baud_base 38400 spd_normal skip_test
```

This configuration setting came from a user the same hardware who was having trouble on the Fedora forums. 
    http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-270181.html

We've also tried serial.conf with these parameters, as described in the linuxquestions.org site.
    (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/howto-get-your-gateway-or-finepoint-pen-working-497879/)

```
    /dev/ttyS0 port 0x03F8 irq 4 baud_base 38400
```

There is a challenge with getting the fpit driver to run under Fedora. It's been cut out of the main branch, and on 19/20 you can no longer just yum install fpit. To get a functioning driver, we dove back into version 16. The ISO is here:

```
    http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/i386/iso/Fedora-16-i386-DVD.iso
```

From there, we were able to download an RPM of fpit driver 1.4.0 for fedora from this URL.

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17319852/dir/fedora_16/com/xorg-x11-drv-fpit-1.4.0-2.fc16.i686.rpm.html

I know it's a shot in the dark to ask about an older distro and a super-specific piece of hardware, but any insight would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: You can always reach into the Koji build service and get the source RPMs and attempt to modify and rebuild them on Fedora 19/20. http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=259318

Comment: I would be tempted to take all the options out of the "InputDevice" section except for the 1st 3. Then reboot. Then fire up `xev` and confirm that the pen is sending events that X can see correctly. I would then add the options back in 1 at a time to see if you actually need them and if they're set values are right.